# Javascript var is null unless first logged

Tags: javascript, heroku

Strangest thing I've seen in a while. This var is `null` unless first logged into the console before accessing.

```
var sidecarOffset = $('#sidecar').offset().top - 50;

// Without this log, `sidecarOffset` is `null` when used below.
console.log(sidecarOffset);

$('#sidecar').affix({
  offset: {
    top: sidecarOffset,
  } 
});
```

Perhaps even stranger, this works fine locally in either case, it is only when deployed to Heroku that this problem exists.

Comment: Can you recreate this on fiddle?

Comment: I doubt it, cause like I said, it works fine with local code, I only have this issue when the code is deployed on Heroku.

Comment: Well that's strange!...try adding a `debugger;` statement just before the `console.log()`and inspect the value of the variable and possibly the value of `$("#sidecar")` or in production try adding a breakpoint instead of the statement